Not able to install anything in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS . Tried multiple ways to uninstall libnode72 but I am looping into the same error again and again
    swathi@swathi-Lenovo-Y50-70:~$ sudo apt install mailutils
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    mailutils : Depends: mailutils-common (= 1:3.14-1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libgsasl7 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libmailutils8 but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: default-mta or mail-transport-agent
    nodejs : Depends: libnode72 (= 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.4) but 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.5 is to be installed
         Recommends: nodejs-doc
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

--------------------------------------------------------------------

swathi@swathi-Lenovo-Y50-70:~$ sudo apt policy nodejs
nodejs:
  Installed: 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 18.20.3-1nodesource1
  Version table:
     18.20.3-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.20.2-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.20.1-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.20.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.19.1-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.19.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.18.2-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.18.1-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.18.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.17.1-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.17.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.16.1-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.16.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.15.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.14.2-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.14.1-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.14.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.13.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.12.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.11.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.10.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.9.1-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.9.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.8.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.7.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.6.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.5.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.4.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.3.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.2.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.1.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     18.0.0-1nodesource1 600
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro/main amd64 Packages
     12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.5 500
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages


sorry but remove the link, make it normal text and copy/paste the text in the image. This site if for ALL to use and improve skills with. Images you can not search and links tend to rot. Both making the value of this very limited

Oh and what to do first is listed twice in the image. did you do that?

The version of nodejs you are trying to install must be foreign. After you fix your question by pasting in the text from your image, please also paste in the text output from apt policy nodejs

Hi,
I have made required changes and also pasted output relavant to "sudo apt policy nodejs"

Does this answer your question? How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?

apt policy does not require sudo. Your package system is broken because the version of nodejs you have installed is not from any source you currently have associated with your computer. Carefully think about whether you actually need that nodejs ppa you have included in your package system.
